# gradle dependency fails but it's there

Tags: maven, gradle, ivy, micrometer

I have the following error (PLEASE NOTE the jar it says it could not find is different from the location jar name in this error...weird)...

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':webserver:webpiecesServerBuilder:templateProject:WEBPIECESxAPPNAME'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':webserver:webpiecesServerBuilder:templateProject:WEBPIECESxAPPNAME:runtime'.
   > Could not find micrometer-core.jar (io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.4.0-SNAPSHOT:20200320.152130-173).
      Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/io/micrometer/micrometer-core/1.4.0-SNAPSHOT/micrometer-core-1.4.0-20200319.235509-170.jar
```

A snapshot of the current contents of directory(in case this post last to tomorrow and a new snapshot is there) is the following...

[image]

I have no idea why it can't find 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT since my gradle file is simple and the dependency is simply

```
'io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.4.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a gradle daemon bug or something. I did rm -rf ./gradle/cache and then it broke with an exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: build_a6ssp86bmi79bk936w466ea1t$_run_closure5$_closure11
    at build_a6ssp86bmi79bk936w466ea1t$_run_closure5.doCall(/Users/dean/workspace/orderly/dataapi-all/dataapi/build.gradle:111)
    at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureSelf(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.configure(AbstractTask.java:587)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.configure(AbstractTask.java:91)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$ContainerElementsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:541)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
```

So then I killed the gradle daemons and voila, it's working again.